# Poweramp access songs from Google Play Music

Tags: audio, music-player, google-play-music, poweramp

I have a Google Play Music subscription and I enjoy the unlimited music, but I don't like the audio quality on Google Play Music.

I was wondering if it was possible to listen to GPM downloaded songs in Poweramp.

Note: I tried GMusic and I had problems with it. Mainly the method for downloading music

Comment: If your device is rooted, you could try [Play Music Exporter](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/de.arcus.playmusicexporter2).

Answer (score -1):

Downloaded songs as in songs you purchased? Yes, their should be MP3 files you saved somewhere and they should show up in PowerAmp or can be imported.

If by downloaded songs you mean Google Play licensed content, streams or cached music, no, you cannot play them with a different player.